# routing express node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following routes methods in my controller:

```
getListaUsuarios() {
    this.app.get("/api/usuario", (req, res) => {
        this.usuario.getListaUsuarios().then((results) => {
            return res.status(200).json(results);
        }).catch((error) => {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        });
    });
}

getUsuarioByEmail() {
    this.app.get("/api/usuario/:usuarioEmail", (req, res) => {
        let usuarioEmail = req.params.usuarioEmail;
        this.usuario.getUsuarioByEmail(usuarioEmail).then((results) => {
            if(!results) return res.status(404).json();
            return res.status(200).json(results);
        }).catch((error) => {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        });
    });
}
```

My question is related with the routes, for best practices we know that we should be using the name of the resources, in the first method I'm retrieving the list of Users and in the second I'm trying to retrieve the user by email. But when I try to call the api with: `localhost:3000/api/usuario?usuarioEmail=xxxx@xxx.com` it always call the first method and not the second. Is there something wrong with the way I'm defining my routes, or I have to change the complete path always.

Comment: you have to escape the email, because '@' isn't allowed. In fact it is used in an url protected via http basic auth like: `http://username:password@example.com/`

Comment: thanks i needed to scape my email too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the url `localhost:3000/api/usuario?usuarioEmail=xxxx@xxx.com`, `usuarioEmail` is a query string; your rout is expecting it as a parameter. The correct usage given your routes would be:

```
localhost:3000/api/usuario/xxxx%40xxx.com
```

Where `%40` represents the URI encoding of `@`.

If you actually wanted to use query strings, you would need to do something like this:

```
getListaUsuarios() {
    this.app.get("/api/usuario", (req, res) => {
        if (!req.query.usarioEmail) { // check for the query string
            let usuarioEmail = req.params.usuarioEmail;
            this.usuario.getUsuarioByEmail(usuarioEmail).then((results) => {
                 if(!results) return res.status(404).json();
                 return res.status(200).json(results);
            }).catch((error) => {
                return res.status(500).send(error);
            });
        } else {
            this.usuario.getListaUsuarios().then((results) => {
                return res.status(200).json(results);
            }).catch((error) => {
                return res.status(500).send(error);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, you were right the url was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are mixing `req.params` with `req.query`

**`req.query`**

Works when you want to use an url just like the one you posted

```
localhost:3000/api/usuario?usuarioEmail=xxxx%40xxx.com
```

and the logic has to be setup in the `/api/usuarios` route

```
getListaUsuarios() {
    this.app.get("/api/usuario", (req, res) => {
      if (req.query.usuarioEmail) { //Aply your logic over here
        /*If wont change the value of usuarioEmail, you should use 
          const instead of let*/
        const usuarioEmail = req.params.usuarioEmail;
        return this.usuario.getUsuarioByEmail(usuarioEmail).then((results) => {
            if(!results) return res.status(404).json();
            return res.status(200).json(results);
        }).catch((error) => {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        });        
      }
        this.usuario.getListaUsuarios().then((results) => {
            return res.status(200).json(results);
        }).catch((error) => {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        });
    });
}
```

**`req.params`**

Is used when you want to do something like this

```
localhost:3000/api/usuario/micorreo%40email.com
```

And your route will look exactly like you have defined it

```
/api/usuario/:usuarioEmail
```

The value of :usuarioEmail is in `req.params.usuarioEmail`

If you want to know more about the req object, here's a link to the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api)

Comment: thanks fo your recommendations about const and let, i appreciate